# posts_nav_link(); picks up index.php instead of category.php as template

Tags: categories, pages, next-post-link

My index.php and category.php pages are different especially in regards to query_posts function.

Both themselves works fine, however when I navigate to "Next Page" via posts_nav_link();, index.php works fine. But, my category.php on second (and so on) page no longer picks up it's custom design but withdraws from index.php which messes up the query (among other things).

Is there any simple solution for this (basically to make posts_nav_link keep using the category.php instead of index.php)? Thanks!

Comment: "... especially in regards to query_posts function" Woah there - [you shouldn't be using `query_posts`, ever](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/1685) - this is more than likely why you're having issues. Can you post the code of `index.php` and `category.php` so we can suggest a better way.